# Find a pattern in key => value?

Tags: pattern-recognition

Sorry if this isn't the correct place but it did seem to be! Basically, I'm coding a small test with a bouncing ball. All works well, but the problem is I need to work out the `b` needed for a ball to bounce a realistic looking height where `b = 'bounce'`. *This isn't a physics question!*

I have worked out `b = distance_from_ground / modifier`. However the modifier needs to be different each time depending on `distance_from_ground`. So I've experimented quite bit and found the following pattern for realistic bouncing.

```
distance_from_ground  |  modifier
50                        12.5
130                       10
330                       5
```

What's the best way of working out a pattern? I want the program to work out the modifier based on the distance_from_ground?

Comment: - linear model : $m(d) := 13.25-d/40$ (default : $12.5\to 12$)      - power model : $m(d):= 14.84-0.118*t^{0.7627}$ (you didn't provide the asymptotics...). But a physical model would be nicer and more reliable !

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you that's awesome! I will switch to a physically accurate model eventually, but this is just a test that's more about testing to technology than anything else :)

Comment: Glad it helped @andy and fine continuation !